# Can't justify text after adding new break line in Woocommerce price using CSS

Tags: css, woocommerce

I hope you are doing well, I'm facing a problem in mobile devices with the font price size, so I decided to use CSS to make a new line using this code

```css
del.amount { display: flex !important;  flex-direction: column !important; }
```

but as shown in this image:

[image: https://prnt.sc/9O-TNQ6iTF7v]

it does not appear as the discount price in the same vertical line, I don't know why, even I was trying a couple of CSS methods still showing the same as in screenshot attached in the link.

Has anyone know how to fix this, I am using Woodmart theme.

This problem occurs only in mobile devices.

Comment: Can you share the code related to the issue? (HTML output) to make tests? Because Woodmart theme is a premium theme and I don't have access to the code.

Comment: Here you have the link, https://prnt.sc/51xNuhJQM3B3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Hope Hope this code will fix the issue :  .price del { font-size : 100% !important }

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Worked, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
.price ins{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Hello iorgv, thanks for the help, it seems your code is working, but that one below worked better.